# NodeJS and MsSQL: request.query not returning a calblack

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do a query on my SQL Server, the connection works fine and rises an error when I change the password.
The "error" is on request.query(sql, callback), this function is not returning a callback

The connection code:

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'ip',
    database: 'database',
    connectionTimeout: '5000',
    requestTimeout: '5000',
    options: {encrypt: true}
};

var pool = function(){
    var conn =  new sql.Connection(config, function(err){
        var request = new sql.Request(conn);
        //console.dir(request);
        return request;
    });
    return conn;
}

module.exports = function(){
    return pool;
}
```

DAO:

```
function CampanhaDAO(connection){
    this._connection = connection;
    //console.log(this._connection)
}

CampanhaDAO.prototype.getCampanhas = function(){
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM notificacao_campanha";

    this._connection.query(sql, function(err, recordset){

        console.log(recordset);
    });
};

module.exports = function(){
    return CampanhaDAO;
};
```

Controller:

```
module.exports.campanhas = function(app, req, res){
    var connection = app.config.dbConnection();
    var campanhaDAO = new app.dao.CampanhaDAO(connection);

    campanhaDAO.getCampanhas(function(error, result){
        console.log("gerou");
        res.send(result);
    });
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: anyone? Please?

Comment: Can you also do `console.log(err)` within the query callback?

Comment: No, there is no answer from the query callback